# Database schema for two different types of elements on map

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, search

I wrote a software for a customer that shows clients on a map (Google Maps).
I store the clients on a table on the MySQL database (table `clients`) and show them on the map using markers. Each clients has an id, name, lat, lon, and other satellite fields.
The customer wanted to add a feature to add notes to the map.
I made a second table (`notes`). Each note has an id, text and lat,lon.

The application now makes two requests to populate the map, one to get the clients, the other to get the notes.
It works very well but now I'm struggling to implement a "search nearby" search on the map. Before the notes I could simply make a MySQL query on the clients sorting them by distance from a given point on the map. Now I should make two queries, but clients and notes could be interleaved:

e.g.

- client12 - 200m
- client8 - 2km
- note10 - 5km
- note3  - 8km
- client1 - 12km

Since I'm using LIMIT/OFFSET on the MySQL query to limit the items returned on each call (the call is reiterated with a different OFFSET if the user scrolls down the list), I don't really know what could be the best approach to combine the two types of items.

Here some options I could think of:

- Intereaving in software after the database queries (sounds a really bad idea. Also must give up the LIMIT/OFFSET part of the query)
- Remove `clients` and `notes` tables and use a single `item` table. Notes now have a lot of NULL fields because clients have a lot of very specific fields not relevant for the notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lat` and `long` fields for both `clients` and `notes` seem to represent the same columns duplicated across multiple tables, which is a violation of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so those columns should be consolidated into a single table (`item`?).

However both `clients` and `notes` tables would also still be required (without their respective `lat`/`long` fields which are in the separate `item` table) to adhere to 3rd Normal Form (3NF).  That is to say that you should avoid the approach of combining those fields which are only meaningful for either `clients` or `notes` into a single table by using `NULL`, since that would imply dependencies between non-key attributes, which is a violation of 3NF.

Recommended reading on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples

---

***Update:*** Just to clarify - the `item` table would contain `lat` and `lon` fields for both `clients` and `notes`, so the distance query which sorts by distance would only need to care about a single table.

The other two tables `clients` and `notes` would only be needed to select additional fields which are specific to those entities;  so for example, if the distance query also needed to include the `[clients].[name]` and `[notes].[text]`, then the query could include a `LEFT JOIN` to pick up those fields where applicable - for example:

```
SELECT i.id, i.lat, i.long, c.name, n.text
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.itemId == i.id
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.itemId == i.id

ORDER BY ...
```

Naturally a LEFT JOIN means that the *query results* will contain `NULL` fields  depending on whether the item is joined to a `clients` or `notes` entry, but that generally isn't a problem because those fields wouldn't have any non-key dependencies in the underlying database.

Comment: ok but this doesn't answer the primary question: how to sort by distance over two  different tables (now with lat,lon on another table "item")

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini - Updated with a bit more information about querying, but the bottom line is that the query you currently use with `clients` should continue to work albeit using `item` instead - and optionally some `LEFT JOIN` clauses to select any specific fields you may want from the other tables.

Comment: now that's very clear now, thank you